# How can I make my score-based game addictive?

Tags: game-design, flash, mathematics, actionscript-3, game-center

I need some ideas to make players interested in the game result.  Otherwise, the player plays again to get high score. My game is a calculation game that measures the speed of calculations that the user makes.

I added in the result:

1. The number of right answers
2. The number of wrong answers
3. Score of player
4. High score of all players -  "Mochi High score"

What shall I add to entice the player to play the game again?

Comment: -1, wrong question.  "How can I make my score-based game addictive" is a very different question than "how can I improve my end of level stats screen".

Comment: Wouldn't it have been more efficient to just rename the question than to vote down?

Comment: OK I'll do my best to fix it .

Comment: Alright, undid my -1.

Comment: Now this feels almost like dup of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4532/what-should-a-game-have-in-order-to-keep-humans-playing-it.

Comment: @Maged, GUESS, its spelled guess, not gauss!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A high score list in which player can see their rank relative to other people may give some motivation. I am not sure if this works for your game, but it may be possible to collect stats like total number of right answers summing up all played matches.

If you use an internet based high score list, it may be a good idea to split it into "recent players" and "all times". The standard approach of only displaying a  all time list has the issue that it will be really hard for new players a couple of month after release.

Comment: OK , I'll use Mocha score. I gauss it's the best one .

Answer (score 5):

Make it very easy to play again, and less easy to quit. For example, as soon as the game is over, display the user's current score and best score.  Have them simply click the mouse (anywhere, not on a particular button) to play again.  This will greatly increase the 'one more time' factor.

Of course, the most important thing is for the game to be fun.  Nobody will play it again if it isn't fun.  If they got a little adrenalin rush at the end of the last game, they'll be eager to give it another shot.  Even calculation games can be fun.

High score lists with worldwide players only provide motivation to very skilled players.  A beginner will simply be discouraged that he's ranked 8 millionth in the world.  Early on, it's better to compare the user with his own previous efforts.

Also, it's nice to have intermediate goals.  Provide the player with something to play for.  It can be as simple as additional skins, powerups, or skills.  Tantalize the user so he's sure he can get that next prize with 'just one more turn.'

Answer (score 2):

First I am going to assume that that evaluation is going to be shown to the player, if so, I would enumerate all the accomplishments he had on that playing session, lets say winning a certain amount of virtual money, reaching a certain level, it can congratulate the player if it was the best game he played so far, and tell him he beat his previous scores.

But if you wanna evaluate him to keep track of him for analyzing it later on, you can store how he plays (style, or player profile), frequency, times at which he plays, and other measures.

Answer (score 1):

You could award badges for achievements. So each time the user finishes a games you could make calculations and let them know if the have been awarded a badge or are close to being awarded (eg: play again to qualify for a new badge!)

Look at the badges on this site for some ideas. Some badge ideas

- Beat your own high score for the day (week etc)
- Beat your own high score 5 games in a row
- Played 10 days consecutively
- Highest score for the day (week etc)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Zynga (Farmville) is very good at generating user compulsion.

Check out an analysis of their techniques [here](http://goo.gl/3JqOn). (URL shortener used because stackexchange doesn't handle URL's with apostrophes very well. Goes to http://meidell.dk/archives/2010/11/25/what-i-learned-from-farmville-so-you-don’t-have-to-play-it/)